# How to use Select in linq

Tags: c#, linq

I am attempting to Select close and DateTime from the candle class. Intellisense does not have an option to select them after selecting a candle...

```
var values = stocks.Select(s => new DateClose() { Time = s.candles., ClosingPrice = s.candles. }); // this does not work after s.candles I expect to see
```

**PriceHistory.cs**

```
    {
        public bool empty { get; set; }
        public string symbol { get; set; }

        public List<Candle> candles { get; set; }
    }
```

**Candle.cs**

```
    {
        public decimal close { get; set; }
        public DateTime datetime { get; set; }
        public decimal high { get; set; }
        public decimal low { get; set; }
        public decimal open { get; set; }
        public long volume { get; set; }

    }
```

**DateClose.cs**

````
    {
        public DateTime Time { get; set; }

        public decimal ClosingPrice { get; set; }

```
````

Comment: Do you have `using Linq;` and are you targeting .NET Framework 3.5 or later with a reference to `System.Core.dll`?

Comment: What is the data type of `stocks`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You likely want to use [`SelectMany`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany?view=netframework-4.8#System_Linq_Enumerable_SelectMany__2_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Func___0_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___1___) here in order to flatten a collection of collections:

```
IEnumerable<DateClose> values = 
    stocks.SelectMany(s => 
        s.candles.Select(c => new DateClose
        { 
            Time = c.datetime,
            ClosingPrice = c.close
        }));
```